# Android App does not show in emulator

Tags: android, load, emulation, boot

I created a new app target the GoogleAPI and a Android Emulator that does the same thing. The problem is that whenever I run the project, my new project does not appear inside the emulator. Does anybody else experience this kind of problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: did U created your emulator with google api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi Did you check the logs at logcat view or console view while starting or installing your application on emulator.

Comment: anyway I got it running when I targeted Android 4.0.3 when I created a new project. I wonder why it didn't work when I targeted the googleAPIs

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new emulator with google API 
and then app in this emulator.